# How do I apply custom CSS to Modal dialog - React-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to React here and I am trying to apply CSS to a Modal dialog.

I've created a css file: /css/mycss.css

**/css/mycss.css**

```
.test {
    width: 90%;
    color: red;
}
```

At the root level, I have my modal dialog JSX file:

**MyModal.jsx**

```
//more code above
<Modal
   {...this.props}
   show={this.state.show}
   onHide={this.hideModal}
   dialogClassName="test"
>
//more code below
```

As I understand it, I'm supposed to use the `dialogClassName` prop to apply CSS to the modal dialog.  I'm trying to access the class selector in my CSS file and pass it into the prop as shown.

Do I have to import the CSS?

```
import test from '/css/mycss.css';
```

That didn't work.  What do I do to get the CSS to show?

**Edit:**

I've tried

```
import styles from './css/mycss.css'; // dialogClassName='styles.test';
import { test } from './css/mycss.css'; // dialogClassName='test';
import .test from './css/mycss.css'; // dialogClassName='test';
import {.test} from './css/mycss.css'; // dialogClassName='.test';
import './css/mycss.css'; // dialogClassName='test';
```

None of that applies the CSS.

**Edit 2:**

I tried `import styles from './css/mycss.css'` again and then did `dialogClassName = {styles.test};`.  That actually worked...but sort of.  The text colors did change to red but the width of the Modal dialog is still pretty stagnant.  It is not 90% of the screen or 10% of the screen no matter what I change the `width` attribute to.  So first, why was the tutorial I was following telling me to pass a string to `dialogClassName`?  And how do I get the width of the modal dialog to change?

Comment: Yes, you have to import that css file ;)

Comment: @Mardzis I'm not sure how to do that properly.  I tried what I had written in my post.  I also tried `import { test } from '/css/mycss.css'` and `import .test from '/css/mycss.css'` and `import { .test } from '/css/mycss.css'`. None of them work.

Comment: Re: questions on your *Edit 2*, import on css are done and parsed by webpack css-loader and it saves css into object that's why you need to use variable on `dialogClassName`

Comment: Makes sense but I was following this documentation: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modal-custom-sizing and the `dialogClassName` takes a string which threw me off.

Comment: If you are new and just starting out in react and don't want to worry about other stuff like webpack, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app It lets you focus on building your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you are using webpack. If you don't have installed [css loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader).

```
npm install css-loader --save-dev
```

Now you can import your partial CSS files in React components. This example is when you have CSS files in the same direction as a js file.

```
import componentStyle from './componentStyle.scss';
```

There are more way how to import css files. This I use because you can go inside the file like this: `className={componentStyle.classInside}`.

**Webpack example:**

```
module.exports = {
   module: {
     loaders: [
       { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
     ]
   }
};
```

Also, you can use SASS, LESS, etc. in the same way.

Comment: Yup, I have webpack and I apparently had the `css-loader` already installed so I just needed that middle portion of your answer in order to make it work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `import './css/mycss.css';`

Path should be relative to the file.

Comment: That didn't work.  In `dialogClassName` do I simply put the name of the class that I want to apply (which in my case is `test`)?  The path is correct.

Comment: Are you using any bundler like webpack? Another alternative is to just import the css file in your `index.html` file.

Comment: I am using `webpack`.  Okay, so I tried something new and it "kind of" worked.  Edited my original post.

Comment: You also need a css loader if you are using webpack

Answer (score 0):

In .js file

```js
import classes from './style.css';
dialogClassName= {classes.myModalStyle} as Modal attribute
```

In style.css

```css
.myModalStyle{
    width: 90%,
    max-width: none!important;
}
```

Note: `max-width: none!important` is the most important part. Without it, resizing the width won't work